# Python move point by matrix and then draw orbit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, orbit

I know how to draw points moved by matrix, like this below

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.random.randn(2) #2*1 matrix
A=np.random.randn(2,2) #2*2 matrix
print ('the content of x：\n{}\n the content of A：\n{}'.format(x,A))

def action(pt,n):
     record=[pt]
     for i in range(n):
         pt= A@pt
         record=np.vstack([record,pt])
     plt.scatter(record[:,1],record[:,1])

action(x,100)
```

the function "action" will draw  something like a line, but I want to move points by matrix and then draw it like an orbit

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER:

plt.scatter(record[:,1],record[:,1]) will feed same values in both x & y dimensions & hence will always return a line. Replace it by:

`X,Y = np.hsplit(record,2)
plt.scatter(X,Y)`

LONG ANSWER:

The main cause behind plot coming out as a line is that you are generating the plot using 2 constants (although randomly generated). I will illustrate using below example:

```
>>> c
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.]])
>>> d
array([ 3.,  4.])
>>> d@c
array([ 11.,  22.])
>>> d@c@c
array([  55.,  110.])
>>> d@c@c@c
array([ 275.,  550.])
```

Notice how all the recursive operation is only multiplying the initial co-ordinate by 5 at each stage.
How to get a non-linear plot??

1. Utilize the variable 'i' which we are calling for loop operation by giving it a power of 2(parabola) or more.
2. Use random numbers populated in the 2 matrices greater than 1. Otherwise all the operations either increase the magnitude in -ve or if b/w (-1,1) the magnitude decreases.
3. Use mathematical functions to introduce non-linearity. Eg:

`pt = pt + np.sin(pt)`

[image: sin component added]

Reflect if using 2 random matrices & looping over them is the only way to achieve the curve. If this activity is independent from your bigger programme etc, then probably try different approach by using mathematical functions which generate the curve you like.